# Negative phantom

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I noticed that `\cos` is somewhat larger then `\sin`, and I thought of using something like `\hphantom{\cos}\neghphantom{\sin}` to add the difference after one of my expressions. However it turns out there is no such command. Anyone know of an alternative? Or perhaps a way of defining such a negative phantom myself?

*edit *
Additional information
I was trying to add the space difference at the end of the expression, so after the `\alpha`. Something like `\sin \alpha ABC+additional spacing`
Using Hendrik's example I could do something like `\mathop{\rlap{$\sin\alpha ABC$}}\hphantom{$\cos\alpha ABC$}` but then the line ABC needs to be present twice, so I am hoping for an alternative.

Comment: Can you show a situation where you'd like to use this?

Comment: Hm, it is a bit of a complicated story about aligning tikz figures, and there might be a better way for my specific case coming to think of it. But I suppose a function like this would be useful in general.

Comment: I probably wouldn't do it, but in this situation you could use `\mathop{\rlap{$\sin$}\hphantom{\cos}}` instead of a negative phantom.

Comment: @HendrikVogt Do I understand correctly this produces a zero width \sin followed by the width of a \cos? That's pretty smart.

Anyware I can read more about the usage of \rlap ?

Comment: @Fictional -- there's a nice little example of `\rlap` in *tex by topic* (`texdoc texbytopic` on a tex live system) in section 5.4.5, p.65.

Comment: @Fictional: Yes, that's correct. And I wrapped the whole thing into a `\mathop` so that before and after it you also get the same spacing as for `\cos`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do with `mathtools`, but I wouldn't recommend it. This leaves a gap on the right of “sin”, but centering it in the available space would be even worse.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\let\sin\relax % remove the previous definition of \sin
\DeclareMathOperator{\sin}{%
  \mathrlap{\operatorname{sin}}\hphantom{\cos}%
}

\begin{document}
$\sin\alpha$

$\cos\alpha$

$e^{\sin x}$

$e^{\cos x}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

A different solution, where you add the space after the `\sin<expression>` can be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\csin}[1]{%
  \mathop{}\!\mathrlap{\sin#1}\hphantom{\cos#1}%
}

\begin{document}
$3\csin{\alpha}+\cos\beta$

$3\cos\alpha+\cos\beta$

$e^{\csin{x}+i\cos{x}}$

$e^{\cos x+i\cos x}$
\end{document}
```

Since we need to know what the argument to `\csin` is, braces delimiting it are necessary.

However, this has limitations because it's difficult to catch the type of the last object in the argument of `\csin`, so this might break with parenthesized expressions and hand corrections would be needed, for instance

```
\csin{(x+y)}\mathclose{}
```

[image]

Yet another proposal: a `\sincorr` space to be added by hand where necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\sincorr}{\mathpalette\dosincorr\relax}
\newcommand{\dosincorr}[2]{%
  \sbox0{$#1\cos$}\sbox2{$#1\sin$}%
  \kern\dimexpr\wd0-\wd2\relax}

\begin{document}
$3\sin\alpha\sincorr+\cos\beta$

$3\cos\alpha+\cos\beta$

$e^{\sin x\sincorr+i\cos x}$

$e^{\cos x+i\cos x}$

\end{document}
```

The output is identical as with the previous solution.

Comment: Perhaps this wasn't clear: I was trying to add the space difference at the end of the expression, so after the \alpha.
Something like '\sin \alpha ABC+additional spacing'

* edit *
Using Hendrik's example I could do something like \mathop{\rlap{$\sin\alpha ABC$}\hphantom{$\cos\alpha ABC$}

Comment: @Fictional No, it wasn't clear. And I still can't think to situations where this would be useful.

Comment: I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Nice edit, I guess this will do  
  
I'll see if anyone else replies. If not I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Is there any way to define a non-math "negative phantom"?

Comment: @AFeldman See [Negative phantom inside equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316426/); my answer works also outside math mode.