# Negative phantom inside equations

Tags: spacing, macros, equations

The following code produces a negative phantom (from the comment in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67914/32291)):

`\newcommand{\negphantom}[1]{\settowidth{\dimen0}{#1}\hspace*{-\dimen0}}`

However, when used inside an equation like

`$$a\negphantom{\inf_{t>0}t^2}b$$`

I get an error. The solution is to do

`$$a\negphantom{$\inf_{t>0}t^2$}b$$`

Is it possible to define `negphantom` in such a way that it respects being inside an equation or not? (the latter solution is not perfect, since the `\inf` is not in displaystyle).

Comment: `\newcommand{\negphantom}[1]{\settowidth{\dimen0}{$#1$}\hspace*{-\dimen0}}`?

Comment: Or better: `\newcommand{\negphantom}[1]{\ifmmode\settowidth{\dimen0}{$#1$}\else\settowidth{\dimen0}{#1}\fi\hspace*{-\dimen0}}`

Comment: @HenriMenke, Thank you! I came up with the first solution myself but I would like to use the command for both text- and math-mode. Your second solution works, but it doesn't respect the displaystyle of the outer equation mode.

Comment: I think perhaps `\mathchoice` checks for the current style, but I'm trying to get it to work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You check for math mode and then use `\mathpalette`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\negph@wd}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\negphantom}[1]{%
  \ifmmode
    \mathpalette\negph@math{#1}%
  \else
    \negph@do{#1}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\negph@math}[2]{\negph@do{$\m@th#1#2$}}
\newcommand{\negph@do}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\negph@wd}{#1}%
%  \hspace*{-\negph@wd}% % for TESTING
  \hspace*{\negph@wd}% % for TESTING
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
a\negphantom{\inf_{t>0}t^2}b \\
a{\inf_{t>0}t^2}b \\
\textstyle a\negphantom{\inf_{t>0}t^2}b \\
\textstyle a{\inf_{t>0}t^2}b \\
\scriptstyle a\negphantom{\inf_{t>0}t^2}b \\
\scriptstyle a{\inf_{t>0}t^2}b \\
\scriptscriptstyle a\negphantom{\inf_{t>0}t^2}b \\
\scriptscriptstyle a{\inf_{t>0}t^2}b
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now that we're sure the space is correct in all cases, we can remove the debugging bits and write down the final definition:

```
\makeatletter
\newlength{\negph@wd}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\negphantom}[1]{%
  \ifmmode
    \mathpalette\negph@math{#1}%
  \else
    \negph@do{#1}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\negph@math}[2]{\negph@do{$\m@th#1#2$}}
\newcommand{\negph@do}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\negph@wd}{#1}%
  \hspace*{-\negph@wd}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: accidentally I found a solution from 1994 which seems to do something similar: http://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/texmacros/nphantom.tex