# How should I format an overbrace straddling a place where I want to align vertcially?

Tags: align, overbrace

```
\begin{align} 
\int \arctan x \, dx & = \overbrace{\int u\,dx = xu - \int x\,du}^
    \text{integration by parts} \\[10pt] & \phantom{{} = \int u\,dx} 
= x\arctan x - \int x\left( \frac{dx}{1+x^2} \right) 
\end{align}
```

I want the overbrace to be right where it is, identifying the basic integration-by-parts identity, and I want the "=" on the next line to be aligned with the one in that identity, and I want to continue this for several more lines with the same alignment. Is there an elegant and efficient way to do this, as opposed to just repeating the phantom on every line?

Comment: Except for the `\,`, this looks good as is.  Do you have a specific problem with it. Oh, and perhaps `\mathrm{d}x`, but that is a matter of taste.  For future reference, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: @PeterGrill : The final result looks good, but the method of coding is cumbersome and inelegant.  I'm trying to do some alignment so it would be nice if just somehow using some alignment tabs could accomplish that.

Comment: You don't like \int f(x)\,dx?  Is \int f(x)~dx what you prefer?

Comment: Since your alignment point is _within_ another macro, I think the use of a `\phantom` (perhaps `\hphantom` would be better as you are only looking for horizontal alignment) is an acceptable approach.  Another option is to use `\tikzmark` and draw the brace separately -- then you do not have to use the `hphantom`, but some would consider that _overkill_. Instead of adding `\,` see if `x \mathrm{d}x` works for you.

Comment: Maybe I should add that I want the alignment to continue for several more lines after that, so adding the same \phantom every time seems inelegant.

Comment: I understand the arguments for \mathrm{d}, but, although it seems commonplace among physicists, mathematicians hardly ever use that.  I want to use notation that is standard among mathematicians (unless there were some instance in which for some reason I actually _disagree_ with it).

Comment: @PeterGrill : What if you want f(x)\,\Delta x?  Would you forgo the spacing?  How about \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\,\partial y} ? No space between the two partials?

Comment: For several more lines use the `\hphantom` (or define a macro fork it).  Adding spacing such as `\,` is a matter of taste, but I highly recommend you define a macro for `\dx` so that it is consistent.

Comment: . . . and besides, if one does write \mathrm{d}, I'd still put the space there: f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x or maybe f(x)~\mathrm{d}x.

Comment: The utility of the \dx macro is noted for future reference.  There's still the thing about partials and capital Delta.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\negphantom` (see [Negative phantom inside equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316426/)) together with `\hphantom`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\negph@wd}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\negphantom}[1]{%
  \ifmmode
    \mathpalette\negph@math{#1}%
  \else
    \negph@do{#1}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\negph@math}[2]{\negph@do{$\m@th#1#2$}}
\newcommand{\negph@do}[1]{%
  \settowidth{\negph@wd}{#1}%
  \hspace*{-\negph@wd}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{align} 
\int \arctan x \diff x = \int u\diff x 
&= \negphantom{\int u\diff x = {}}
   \overbrace{\hphantom{\int u\diff x = {}}xu - \int x\diff u}
     ^\text{integration by parts}
\\[10pt] 
&= x\arctan x - \int x\left( \frac{\diff x}{1+x^2} \right) 
\\[10pt] 
&= x\arctan x - \int x\left( \frac{\diff x}{1+x^2} \right) 
\\[10pt] 
&= x\arctan x - \int x\left( \frac{\diff x}{1+x^2} \right) 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Note the `\diff` command to automatically get the thin space.

[image]

Comment: \diff takes longer to type than \,d.  And it's not suggestive of the meaning, as \,d is.