# Dots in the middle of a row

Tags: math-mode, positioning

How can I put the dots in the middle of the last line? The following doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a&=a+a+a+a+a\\
a&=a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a\\
\vdotswithin{a=a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps `\ldots` should do the trick on its own line.

Comment: You should use in the last row `&\vdotswithin{=}`. `\vdotswithin` just aligns the dots in the middle of the witdth of the argument, that way, after the alignment point `&` you are aligning the dots to the middle of the equal sign width.

Comment: @Manuel I want the dots in the middle

Comment: In the middle of what? Of the whole last line? You can do `\sbox0{$a$} \kern-\wd0` before your `\vdotshwithin{..}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't tell anybody, it's a secret:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a&=a+a+a+a+a\\
a&=a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a\\
\multispan{2}\hfill\vdots\hfill
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

(I removed whatever unnecessary for the example.)

[image]

Comment: (+1) I didn't know this one. Thanks! I hope I made good usage in an addendum to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this, based on the `eqparbox` package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools, eqparbox}

\newcommand\eqmathbox[2][1]{\eqmakebox[#1]{\ensuremath{\displaystyle#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  a & =a+a+a+a+a \\
  a & =\eqmathbox[ls]{ a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a} \\[-1ex]
    & ⋮ within{=}\eqmathbox[ls]{ ⋮ } \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Taking advantage of @egreg's secret, the following code produces the same result (note no space must be left in the 3rd row code):

```
\begin{align*}
a&=a+a+a+a+a\\
a&= a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a\\[-1ex]
 &\multispan{1}\ensuremath{\vdotswithin{=}}\hfill\vdots\hfill
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking for instance [egreg's definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/316429/21930) you can just do in the last line `&\negphantom{a}\vdotswithin{a=a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a+a}`

```
\makeatletter
\newlength\negph@wd
\DeclareRobustCommand*\negphantom[1]
  {\ifmmode\mathpalette\negph@math{#1}%
   \else\negph@do{#1}\fi}
\newcommand*\negph@math[2]{\negph@do{$#1#2\m@th$}}
\newcommand*\negph@do[1]
  {\settowidth{\negph@wd}{#1}\hspace*{-\negph@wd}}
\makeatother
```